# Action When Clicking an Item of collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have `FlexLayout` that I use to display the contents of the collection. I want to realize the possibility that when you click on an element of the collection, the command is executed. I want to make sure that when you click on an item, another view is loaded that loads data that corresponds to the selected day. How do I get collection items to react to clicks?

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="5"
              HeightRequest="120"
              WidthRequest="105">
            <BoxView Color="Azure" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Day}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Margin="10">
    <Label Text="CollectionView"
           FontSize="30"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Label Text="{Binding MyCollection.Count, StringFormat='Count: {0}'}" />
    <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout Direction="Row" 
                        Wrap="Wrap"
                        AlignItems="Center"
                        AlignContent="Center"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
                        BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColorItemTemplate}"/>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: Result]

> but when clicking on an item, where do you want to send data to?

In the screenshot above, you can see 20 objects in the collection. They are created in the class constructor and they display the time at which they were created.

```
PowerTrainings = new ObservableCollection<PowerTraining>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                PowerTrainings.Add(new PowerTraining() { DayOfTraining = dateTime });
            }
```

According to my idea, every time a user (in particular, I, because I do it for myself) will choose a particular day from the history, another view will be loaded, which will display the exercises that he did on that day. But how to correctly implement in the XAML code a code that will determine that this particular element of the collection was clicked (in which dates are displayed) and pass this date to another view, which, based on the property `DayOfTraining` , will make a query to the database with classes on this day and form another collection?

Comment: `I want to make sure that when you click on an item, another view is loaded that loads data that corresponds to the selected day` What do you mean by words `another view`? Can you explain it in detail? In addition, could you please post a basic demo or the other code snippets of your app (e.g. the viewmodel)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle touch event for a FlexLayout in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756361/how-to-handle-touch-event-for-a-flexlayout-in-xamarin). Please show contents of `ColorItemTemplate`, which is your `BindableLayout.ItemTemplate`. Solution is to add a tap recognizer to that template.

Comment: Slight change from that example: add tap recognizer to the outermost layout of your template. E.g. if its a `StackLayout`, under the stacklayout declaration line, add `<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers><TapGestureRecognizer Command=...` [Tap Gesture Recognizer doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT https://denis-andreevich.visualstudio.com/_git/SportApp?path=%2FSportApp&version=GBalpha&_a=contents

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT If I represent it by analogy with WPF, then I would create a MouseDoubleClick event and pass the object to another view through the SelectedIndex property. But in the case of Xamarin, I don't understand (yet) how everything works. Considering that everything is done on the smartphone screen by tapping on the screen.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT hold on please

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT https://github.com/rammfire/SportApp/tree/alpha

Comment: Do you want to pass the selected `DayOfTraining ` to this page or to other page?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT yes :) And I don't understand how you can find out which element the user clicked on. To load information for a specific day.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part at the bottom of of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I represent it by analogy with WPF, then I would create a
> MouseDoubleClick event and pass the object to another view through the
> SelectedIndex property. But in the case of Xamarin, I don't understand
> (yet) how everything works.

I could deploy your app to my emulator, but when clicking on an item, where do you want to send data to?

Depending on the scenario, there are several ways to pass data between two Views.

A simple method is to use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

The Xamarin.Forms [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter?view=xamarin-forms) class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references. This mechanism allows publishers and subscribers to communicate without having a reference to each other, helping to reduce dependencies between them.

**Publish a message**

Publishers notify subscribers of a message with one of the MessagingCenter.Send overloads. The following code example publishes a `Hi` message:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi");
```

**Subscribe to a message**

Subscribers can register to receive a message using one of the MessagingCenter.Subscribe overloads.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) =>
{
    // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
});
```

**Unsubscribe from a message**

Subscribers can unsubscribe from messages they no longer want to receive. This is achieved with one of the MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe overloads:

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage>(this, "Hi");
```

**Update:**

> And I don't understand how you can find out which element the user
> clicked on

You can add [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) for your `DataTemplate`.

I modified your `DataTemplate` and add `TapGestureRecognizer` for it. You can refer the following code：

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorItemTemplate">
        <Frame Margin="5"
              HeightRequest="120"
              BackgroundColor="Azure"
              WidthRequest="105">
            <Label Text="{Binding DayOfTraining}" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.TypeListSelectedCommand, Source={x:Reference flexLayout}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

In class `TrainingViewModel`,add  command `TypeListSelectedCommand` as follows:

```
    public ICommand TypeListSelectedCommand => new Command<PowerTraining>(selectedItem);

     void selectedItem(PowerTraining obj)
    {
        PowerTraining item = obj as PowerTraining;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("clicked item = " + item.DayOfTraining);
    }
```

Note:
1.`flexLayout` is the x:Name of your `FlexLayout`:

```
  <FlexLayout  x:Name="flexLayout"   />
```

In addition, you can add `TapGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ColorItemTemplate">
        <Frame Margin="5"
              HeightRequest="120"
              BackgroundColor="Azure"
              WidthRequest="105">
            <Label Text="{Binding DayOfTraining}" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And in `CalendarOfTraining.xaml.cs`,add function `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped`:

```
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Frame boxView = sender as Frame;
        PowerTraining SelectedItem = (PowerTraining)boxView.BindingContext;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" clicked item = " + SelectedItem.DayOfTraining);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I'm closer than ever to the goal. But, I have the following feature with the first solution option (everything is fine with the second one with code behind). For some reason, command is looking for its implementation in the wrong class: `[0:] Binding: 'TypeListSelectedCommand' property not found on 'SportApp.Models.PowerTraining',`, but my command in `TrainingViewModel.cs`